# Navigate to custom lightning component from link in lightning community

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, community, lightning-community

I want to redirect to my custom component from link in lightning community but on click of link it is redirecting to home page it self.

```
var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
var url = 'https://test-developer- 
edition.na71.force.com/PartnerRKC/s/lightning/cmp/c__avTest';
urlEvent.setParams({"url": url});
urlEvent.fire();
```

Can you please guide me what i am missing here?

Comment: It is not going to work in this way, you need to add Lightning Event in your code to navigate to other component. Follow the link for more information.                                                                         
https://force-base.com/2016/01/04/how-to-navigate-from-one-component-to-another-in-lightning/

Comment: Ohh..!!!! so i need to create one event which will redirect me to my avTest component?@SFDCChamp

Comment: Yes, I don't think you will be able to redirect without creating event. You can try by creating event.

Comment: Thank you!! i ll check if its working for me or not.!!!!@SFDCChamp